# Сохранение вложений из imap-сообщений на диск

Tags: php, imap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте, я в пхп полный 0 поставили задачу выгружать с почты вложения, я нашел рабочий скрипт только он не выгружает файлы с русским названием.
я понимаю что нужно где то задать параметр iconv UTF-8 а от где и как хз, убил несколько дней на изучение пхп но толку 0.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
set_time_limit(3000);

$hostname = '{imap.ukr.net:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = ''; # например somebody@gmail.com
$password = '';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
$max_emails = 16;

if($emails) {

    $count = 1;
     rsort($emails);
     foreach($emails as $email_number)
    {

        /* get information specific to this email */              
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        /* get mail message */
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++)
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters)
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object)
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename')
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters)
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object)
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name')
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment'])
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3)

                       {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */  
                 elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4)
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }


                }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                  if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . "dat";

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                 * have the attachment with the same file name.
                 */
        $fp = fopen('/mnt/c/ubuntu/pochta/'. $filename, 'w+');
              fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
             fclose($fp);
            }

        }

        if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;
    }

}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

echo "Done\n";

?>
```

Comment: У тебя в коде нет отладки ошибок . Пользуйся `imap_last_error()`.Например  `$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);` if (FALSE === $overview) {
 throw new Exception('FetchOverview failed: ' . imap_last_error());
}`

Answer (score 1):

[Save attachments from imap messages to disk.](https://gist.github.com/hakre/2363305)

Ниже приведены примеры кода. Код этих классов более или менее обертывает функции imap _..., но для классов вложений он также выполняет синтаксический анализ структур (смотреть Часть 2).

**Часть 1 - инициализация классов:**

```
/**
 * Utility Class
 */
class IMAP
{
    /**
     *
     * =?x-unknown?B?
     * =?iso-8859-1?Q?
     * =?windows-1252?B?
     *
     * @param string $stringQP
     * @param string $base (optional) charset (IANA, lowercase)
     * @return string UTF-8
     */
    public static function decodeToUTF8($stringQP, $base = 'windows-1252')
    {
        $pairs = array(
            '?x-unknown?' => "?$base?"
        );
        $stringQP = strtr($stringQP, $pairs);
        return imap_utf8($stringQP);
    }
}
class IMAPMailbox implements IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    private $stream;
    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password)
    {
        $stream = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password);
        if (FALSE === $stream) {
            throw new Exception('Connect failed: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        $this->stream = $stream;
    }
    public function getStream()
    {
        return $this->stream;
    }
    /**
     * @return stdClass
     */
    public function check()
    {
        $info = imap_check($this->stream);
        if (FALSE === $info) {
            throw new Exception('Check failed: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        return $info;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $criteria
     * @param int $options
     * @param int $charset
     * @return IMAPMessage[]
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function search($criteria, $options = NULL, $charset = NULL)
    {
        $emails = imap_search($this->stream, $criteria, $options, $charset);
        if (FALSE === $emails) {
            throw new Exception('Search failed: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        foreach ($emails as &$email) {
            $email = $this->getMessageByNumber($email);
        }
        return $emails;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $number
     * @return IMAPMessage
     */
    public function getMessageByNumber($number)
    {
        return new IMAPMessage($this, $number);
    }
    public function getOverview($sequence = NULL)
    {
        if (NULL === $sequence) {
            $sequence = sprintf('1:%d', count($this));
        }
        return new IMAPOverview($this, $sequence);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve an external iterator
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iteratoraggregate.getiterator.php
     * @return Traversable An instance of an object implementing Iterator or
     * Traversable
     */
    public function getIterator()
    {
        return $this->getOverview()->getIterator();
    }
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return $this->check()->Nmsgs;
    }
}
class IMAPOverview extends ArrayObject
{
    private $mailbox;
    public function __construct(IMAPMailbox $mailbox, $sequence)
    {
        $result = imap_fetch_overview($mailbox->getStream(), $sequence);
        if (FALSE === $result) {
            throw new Exception('Overview failed: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        $this->mailbox = $mailbox;
        foreach ($result as $overview)
        {
            if (!isset($overview->subject)) {
                $overview->subject = '';
            } else {
                $overview->subject = IMAP::decodeToUTF8($overview->subject);
            }
        }
        parent::__construct($result);
    }
    /**
     * @return IMAPMailbox
     */
    public function getMailbox()
    {
        return $this->mailbox;
    }
}
class IMAPMessage
{
    private $mailbox;
    private $number;
    private $stream;
    public function __construct(IMAPMailbox $mailbox, $number)
    {
        $this->mailbox = $mailbox;
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->stream = $mailbox->getStream();
    }
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $number
     * @return string
     */
    public function fetchBody($number)
    {
        return imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $this->number, $number);
    }
    /**
     * @return stdClass
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function fetchOverview()
    {
        $result = imap_fetch_overview($this->stream, $this->number);
        if (FALSE === $result) {
            throw new Exception('FetchOverview failed: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        list($result) = $result;
        foreach ($result as &$prop) {
            $prop = imap_utf8($prop);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function fetchStructure()
    {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->stream, $this->number);
        if (FALSE === $structure) {
            throw new Exception('FetchStructure failed: ' . imap_last_error());
        }
        return $structure;
    }
    /**
     * @return IMAPAttachments
     */
    public function getAttachments()
    {
        return new IMAPAttachments($this);
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->number;
    }
}
class IMAPAttachment
{
    private $attachment;
    private $message;
    public function __construct(IMAPMessage $message, $attachment)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->attachment = $attachment;
    }
    /**
     * @return string;
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->message->fetchBody($this->attachment->number);
    }
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return (int)$this->attachment->bytes;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtension()
    {
        return pathinfo($this->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }
    public function getFilename()
    {
        $filename = $this->attachment->filename;
        NULL === $filename && $filename = $this->attachment->name;
        return $filename;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        $encoding = $this->attachment->encoding;
        switch ($encoding) {
            case 0: // 7BIT
            case 1: // 8BIT
            case 2: // BINARY
                return $this->getBody();
            case 3: // BASE-64
                return base64_decode($this->getBody());
            case 4: // QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                return imap_qprint($this->getBody());
        }
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Encoding failed: Unknown encoding %s (5: OTHER).', $encoding));
    }
}
class IMAPAttachments extends ArrayObject
{
    private $message;
    public function __construct(IMAPMessage $message)
    {
        $array = $this->setMessage($message);
        parent::__construct($array);
    }
    private function setMessage(IMAPMessage $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        return $this->parseStructure($message->fetchStructure());
    }
    private function parseStructure($structure)
    {
        $attachments = array();
        if (!isset($structure->parts)) {
            return $attachments;
        }
        foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $part)
        {
            if (!$part->ifdisposition) continue;
            $attachment = new stdClass;
            $attachment->isAttachment = FALSE;
            $attachment->number = $index + 1;
            $attachment->bytes = $part->bytes;
            $attachment->encoding = $part->encoding;
            $attachment->filename = NULL;
            $attachment->name = NULL;
            $part->ifdparameters
                && ($attachment->filename = $this->getAttribute($part->dparameters, 'filename'))
                && $attachment->isAttachment = TRUE;
            $part->ifparameters
                && ($attachment->name = $this->getAttribute($part->parameters, 'name'))
                && $attachment->isAttachment = TRUE;
            $attachment->isAttachment
                && $attachments[] = new IMAPAttachment($this->message, $attachment);
        }
        return $attachments;
    }
    private function getAttribute($params, $name)
    {
        foreach ($params as $object)
        {
            if ($object->attribute == $name) {
                return IMAP::decodeToUTF8($object->value);
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

**Часть 2 - демо-код о том, как использовать этот класс с imap_search "ALL", имеющее вложения**:

```
$savedir = __DIR__ . '/imap-dump/';// Указываем директорию куда хотим сохранять файлы 

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';// 
$username = 'somebody@gmail.com';
$password = 'XXXXXXXX';
$inbox = new IMAPMailbox($hostname, $username, $password);

$emails = $inbox->search('ALL');
if ($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        //.........
        //.........
        foreach ($email->getAttachments() as $attachment) {
            $savepath = $savedir . $attachment->getFilename();
            file_put_contents($savepath, $attachment);
        }
    }
}
```