# PHP, IMAP, сохранение вложений

Tags: php, imap

[Сохранение вложений из imap-сообщений на диск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793287/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-imap-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba#comment2746837_1528300)

Использую imap-attachment.php https://gist.github.com/hakre/2363305

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить subject к имени файла при сохранении.

Спасибо!